# React pass data to parent error this.props. is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data from child to parent. Im not sure why I am getting this console error

> TypeError: this.props.aaaaaaaaaa is not a function

Code:

```
class GenericInputWithLabel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    renderLabel() {
        return (
            <div style={labelDiv}>
                {this.props.label}
            </div>
        )
    }

    handleInputChange(inputStr) {
        initialValue={this.props.initialValue}
        this.props.aaaaaaaaaa(inputStr);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={parentDiv}>
                <div style={inputDiv}>
                    <CustomNumberInput
                        initialValue={this.props.initialValue}
                        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                </div>
                {this.props.label && this.renderLabel()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GenericInputWithLabel;
```

Also, the console log I put in inside the handleInputChange does log out the initial value I pass in. This means that the function does have the right context of this. Why would it complain when I want to pass data with

```
this.props.aaaaaaaaaa(inputStr)
```

---Update----

```
<GenericInputWithLabel
    label="test"
    initialValue={123}
    aaaaaaaaaa={this.handleChange}/>
```

Comment: Please show the code where GenericInputWithLabel gets used.

Comment: This shouldn't have anything with how it gets used right?Because I the error is happening at this level so where ever it gets used does not know anything about this due to the error

Comment: I want to see what you’re passing as the aaaaaaaaaa prop since the error is telling you it is not a function. Please show how this.handleChange is being set.

Comment: `aaaaaaaaaa` should be the function. So you must have `this.handleChange` function defined in your parents. So when you pass `this.handleChange` as function from parent it get passed as `props` to child and then from there you can call this parent function. I hope now everything is clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Iv found the problem. It is actually the parent container.

I didn't realise parent container would be the cause.

My constructor this.bind had a typo so everything was not working as expected

Answer (score -1):

You should defined `aaaaaaaaaa` as a function

```
<GenericInputWithLabel aaaaaaaaaa={(str) => console.log(str)}/>
```

Comment: This is not the solution. This is where it gets used at the parent. But the issue is at the child. I cant pass it up because of that error